# How to add target="_blank" into a URL in php on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, target

I have used the following codes to add target="_blank" to a URL (password-reset page) on my website:

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'my_lost_password_page', 10, 2 );
function my_lost_password_page( $lostpassword_url, $redirect ) {
    return home_url( '/password-reset/?redirect_to=target="_blank"' . $redirect );
}
}
```

It does not work as it still opens the same window when pressing that page URL.

Can you please give a right direction?

Comment: `target` is an attribute of the `a` element. Trying to put it into the URL as a parameter is nonsense.

Comment: so what is your advice?

Comment: That you go read [ask] first of all, and then properly explain what it is you want to achieve here to begin with. _“It does not work as it still opens a new window”_ - if you _don’t_ want a new window, then why are you trying to _add_ `target="_blank"` in the first place? _That_ means open in a new window, so if you want the opposite to happen that makes no sense whatsoever either.

Comment: @CBroe, sorry I for mistyping. Post has been edited

Comment: Well that doesn’t address the issue, that this makes no sense to begin with. Again, putting a parameter named `target` into a URL has no effect on this whatsoever.

Comment: Yeah, that’s funny. This is supposed to be a Q&A site, meaning people looking for an answer to similar problems in the future are supposed to find something helpful here without having to ask again, ideally. But that requires that questions are kept to a certain quality and standard to begin with - and yours falls rather short on that so far. You did not even manage to state in clear, non-ambigous terms what exactly it is you want to achieve here. _That_ is _“not helpful to the community”_.

Comment: @CBroe, I know you are the GREATEST WP expert in the world here. I am sorry I am not as good as you are.

Comment: Absolutely not what this is about. I am, same as many others here, more than happy to help to the best of my abilities - _if_ the person asking makes a reasonable effort to begin with. The minimum we expect in that regard, is outlined in [ask]. Because you couldn’t so far, you are now dealing with a low-quality “answer” that does not even look like the person giving it understood what you actually want to achieve here. Which, I hope you realize that, brings us right back to _your_ responsibility of _properly_ explaining that to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code i am not sure with below code but this is the only possible way.

```
//$redirect = "https://www.gooogle.com";
echo '<script>window.open(' . $redirect . ',"_blank");</script>';
```

Comment: thanks. How can I insert into this line of code which involves WP redirect: return home_url( '/password-reset/?redirect_to=target="_blank"' . $redirect );

Comment: According to me you do not required anything past my code instead of your code

Comment: what you mean? I tried to insert your codes without modification, it generates errors in Dreamwaver, so I wont test it.

Comment: thanks again for your help. Yes, I tried it, but it wont redirect to my custom password reset. The above code is about redirecting default WP passwordloss page to a custom page; without $redirect variable, it will redirect to something else.

Comment: check it again please

Comment: it does not work. I found a link for setting the whole page for _blank here: http://www.draghici.net/2016/03/13/wordpress-add-target_blank-content/   but that may be not a good idea if we want only one link to be _blank

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the latest version of RegistrationMagic a momment ago, there is no need to edit the codes I posted above. It is working as intended. Many thanks especially for @Aki. However, if anyone could help guide how to insert that _blank into the above codes, that may be useful for many people. Thanks